# Вывести очень много строк через GridView ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp

Есть простое ASP приложение на котором нужно вывести очень большую таблицу.
На форме расположен грид вью:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="VTable" runat="server" Width="774px" style="margin-left: 0px"/>
```

Достаточно тривиально ему указан источник данных :

```
   private  void UploadTable(string command)
    {
        DataTable TABLE = DBWorker.ReturnTable(command));
        VTable.DataSource = TABLE;
        VTable.DataBind();
    }
```

Однако на моменте привязки DataBind() выскакивает исключение `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Прочитал что исключение вызвано тем что в гридвью нельзя записать более 400 000 строк. Однако в таблице их более миллиона, что с этим делать ?

Comment: А зачем выводить такое количество строк ? кто и что в такой таблице будет искать ? Не проще ли сделать вывод только того , что нужно пользователю , задав фильтр для вывода данных .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю не один уважающий себя и пользователей программист не выведет более миллиона строк на одной странице. Это не удобно и потребляет приличное кол-во ресурсов (особенно для сервера).

Для таких целей разбивают на страницы, на одной странице скажем 50 строк, а в самом низу, под таблицей выводится `Страница 1.2.3... 90`.

Сделайте это:

- Разбейте ваши данные по частям, скажем запросом берете по 50 элементов, начиная с n-го.
- Высчитайте сколько у вас будет всего страниц.
- Сделайте простейший get запрос, где будет указана нужная страницы (site.ru/data?page=10)
- Выведите все страницы в одну строку под таблицу (как я показывал выше).

Ведь в таком случае вы будете брать не миллион записей и выводить их, а небольшими пачками и только по требованию. Это куда удобнее, как для вас, так и для пользователя. Я уже не говорю про нагрузку на сервер при получение "более миллиона строк".

Comment: Можете дать простой пример? asp 2 день изучаю

Comment: @Сергей https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/17.7.php

Comment: Этот пример для Web Forms работает или только для MVC?

Comment: @Сергей, я вам дал один из возможных вариантов. Вы можете сами это написать, без использования сторонних библиотек. Просто перегрузите контрол, что бы он принимал get запросом int переменную pages и по ней определяйте, какие данные выводить, в вашем запросе добавьте `.skip(x).take(y)`, где `x` - от какого элемента брать и `y` - сколько элементов брать. То есть скажем у вас `pages` = 1, берем от первого элемента коллекции и до нашего ограничителя (50 скажем). Далее `pages` = 2, берем от 50 элемента и до 100. Ну и так далее.